# MapsActivity.java doesn't work on android versions higher than 6.0

Tags: java, android, version, android-manifest

I am developing on maps activity. My code works on android 4.4 properly but on another device which is 6.0, doesn't work.

Even doesn't make toast which i wrote under onCreate().That means, mapsActivity.java doesn't work. i dont know why. my java, manifest and gradle below.

thanks.

**mapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { return; }
    Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //toast and the rest of the code doesn't work on 6.0 and high.
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("ref");
```

**my manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**my gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
     }
   }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
  }
```

Comment: you need to debug your app to get why it *doesn't work*

Comment: Ok, I see now. That's because you do `return;` in  case if you don't have the promissions. It is not enough just to check the permissions, you have to request them too

Comment: What makes app crash?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in onCreate method of your 1st activity and feel free to contact me again if any error persists. This will check for **LOCATION permission** and will ask for it in case it hasn't been granted.

Every Android app requires permissions on runtime since Android M(API 23)

```
Here, 'this' is the current activity

if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Permission is not granted
// Should we show an explanation?

if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,"Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed; request the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{"Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"},
                REQUEST_CODE);

     // REQUEST_CODE is an
     // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
     // result of the request.
  }
}

else {
        // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Comment: thank you. after i request permission between check, it fixed.